# Pushing List<string> data to logger.Info in Log4Net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, log4net-appender

I have a huge list of data say like 5k values and I want to push them into the logger.Info of log4net.

If there are individual string values, I am able to do so and accordingly modified the conversion pattern but now I want to push all those values in the list and thus is there anyway I can do so.

Also, I need to modify the conversion pattern too. For conversion pattern, i can make a string using for loop and override the Patternlayout class and set the conversion pattern for all the 5k values but how to put those values from List to those values?

```
string convpatt = "%date{M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss.fff}%newfield%property{Latitude}";

        for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
        {
            log4net.ThreadContext.Properties[i.ToString()] = i.ToString();
            convpatt += "%newfield%property{" + i.ToString()+"}";
        }

        var appenders = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders();

        foreach (var rollingFileAppender in appenders.OfType<log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender>())
        {
            log4net.Layout.PatternLayout myPatten = new MyPatternLayout ();
            My_app.MyPatternLayout mypatt1 = new MyPatternLayout();
            mypatt1.ConversionPattern = convpatt;

            mypatt1.AddConverter("newfield", typeof(NewFieldConverter));
            mypatt1.ActivateOptions();
            rollingFileAppender.Layout = mypatt1;
            rollingFileAppender.ActivateOptions();
        }
```